# Redirect to prepared template in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a question about Docusign API. I want to redirect a user from my website to a prepared template in Docusign. The prepared template has fields to fill but I'm not sure if it is posible to redirect to fill a template. I was able to send the template via email, but if I apply the same logic the API returns an error because expect a file.

Could you please let me know if this is possible? Thanks

Comment: do you mean redirect to the template to author it? or redirect to an envelope created from a template to send it? or redirect to sign an envelope created from a template? all three can be done BTW

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, be sure to accept it. Thanks

Comment: No, at the end I take the option to send the document via email, but we discovered that is necessary in the template in DocusignUI specify only a rol and not an account relate with that rol. With that change it runs for us. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement embedded signing for your app using a template. This workflow is distinct in that no email is sent to your recipient. Instead, your end-user is redirected to DocuSign based on your app logic.

Before beginning, ensure you have a template prepared. You can do this via our API or in the DocuSign UI. I, personally, suggest building out your templates in the UI and then referencing them using requests to our API.

First, you will want to create an envelope using a template. My template example has two signer roles that need to be populated on creation.

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
Authorization: Bearer {enter_access_token}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: text/plain
{
  "status" : "sent",
  "templateId" : "{enter_template_ID}",
  "templateRoles" : [ {
    "email" : "matt_test@mailinator.com",
    "name" : "Matt Test",
    "clientUserId": 1,
    "roleName" : "Buyer",
    "routingOrder" : "1"
  }, {
    "email" : "matt_test2@mailinator.com",
    "name" : "Matt Test2",
    "clientUserId": 2,
    "roleName" : "Seller",
    "routingOrder" : "1"
  } ]
}
```

A successful response will deliver you a payload containing the `envelopeId`. You'll need this to generate your recipientViewUrl(s). Let's do that now for my first recipient.

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account_ID}/envelopes/{envelopeId_from_last_step}/views/recipient HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
Authorization: Bearer {enter_access_token}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: text/plain
{
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost/returnUrl",
  "authenticationMethod": "None",
  "email": "matt_test@mailinator.com",
  "userName": "Matt Test",
  "clientUserId": 1
}
```

A successful response will deliver you a payload containing the `url`. You can now redirect your user.

For a full guide on Embedded Signing, check out [this page on the Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing)